# Formula to calculate wins and losses

Tags: excel

I am making an Excel spreadsheet for UFC data. The next thing I'd like to do is add a couple columns into a sheet to track the record of a fighter (wins, losses, draws and no contest) after each fight on the sheet.

An example of the current data is as follows

```
fighter1, fighter2, fighter1outcome, fighter2 outcome    
Michael Bisping, Luke Rockhold, w, l
```

Wins are always fighter1, losses are always fighter2 but there are some draws and no contests as well.

Is there a formula that could check for every previous fight the fighter had before, check the outcome field and count the number of times it happened? I was looking at COUNTIF statements but I couldnt seem to get anywhere

EDIT 1:
it was suggested to share some of the data and expected outcomes in the original post, so here is the first 20 lines with expected win and loss for both fighters:

```
fight#, fightEventID,   fightFighter1,  fightFighter2,  fightFighter1outcome,   fightFighter2outcome, fighter1wins, fighter1losses, fighter2wins, fighter2losses    
1,  1,  JasonDeLucia,   TrentJenkins,   w,  L, 0, 0, 0, 0    
2,  1,  GerardGordeau,  TeilaTuli,  w,  L, 0, 0, 0, 0    
3,  1,  KevinRosier,    ZaneFrazier,    w,  L, 0, 0, 0, 0    
4,  1,  RoyceGracie,    ArtJimmerson,   w,  L, 0, 0, 0, 0    
5,  1,  KenShamrock,    PatrickSmith,   w,  L, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0    
6,  1,  GerardGordeau,  KevinRosier,    w,  L, 1, 0, 1, 0    
7,  1,  RoyceGracie,    KenShamrock,    w,  L, 1, 0, 1, 0    
8,  1,  RoyceGracie,    GerardGordeau,  w,  L, 2, 0, 2, 0    
9,  2,  RoyceGracie,    MinokiIchihara, w,  L, 3, 0, 0, 0    
10, 2,  JasonDeLucia,   ScottBaker, w,  L, 1, 0, 0, 0    
11, 2,  RemcoPardoel,   AlbertaCerraLeon,   w,  L, 0, 0, 0, 0    
12, 2,  OrlandoWiet,    RobertLucarelli,    w,  L, 0, 0, 0, 0    
13, 2,  FrankHamaker,   ThaddeusLuster, w,  L, 0, 0, 0, 0    
14, 2,  JohnnyRhodes,   DavidLevicki,   w,  L, 0, 0, 0, 0    
15, 2,  PatrickSmith,   RayWizard,  w,  L, 0, 1, 0, 0    
16, 2,  ScottMorris,    SeanDaugherty,  w,  L, 0, 0, 0, 0    
17, 2,  RoyceGracie,    JasonDeLucia,   w,  L, 4, 0, 2, 0    
18, 2,  RemcoPardoel,   OrlandoWiet,    w,  L, 1, 0, 1, 0    
19, 2,  JohnnyRhodes,   FredEttish, w,  L, 1, 0, 0, 0    
20, 2,  PatrickSmith,   ScottMorris,    w,  L, 2, 0, 2, 0
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand what is wanted if you would mock up some data and expected outcome and paste it as text in the original post.

Comment: Ok thanks Scott, I was trying but struggled putting it into words, I have put a mock up of what I want underneath the main post as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTIFS().  You can set the Range part dynamic by anchoring the first cell and leaving the second cell as relative.

So in G2:

```
=COUNTIFS(C$1:C1,$C2,E$1:E1,"W")
```

H2:

```
=COUNTIFS(D$1:D1,$C2,F$1:F1,"L")
```

I2:

```
=COUNTIFS(C$1:C1,$C2,E$1:E1,"D")+COUNTIFS(D$1:D1,$C2,F$1:F1,"D")
```

J2:

```
=COUNTIFS(C$1:C1,$D2,E$1:E1,"W")
```

K2:

```
=COUNTIFS(D$1:D1,$D2,F$1:F1,"L")
```

L2:

```
=COUNTIFS(C$1:C1,$D2,E$1:E1,"D")+COUNTIFS(D$1:D1,$D2,F$1:F1,"D")
```

Then copy down

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, would there be a way to account for draws in the countif method as well? or would that make it a lot more difficult?

Comment: How would a draw look?

Comment: in the outcome columns, instead of having "W" and "L", I would have a "D" in both columns.

Comment: Thats perfect, Thanks a lot Scott!